# Better granularity in Angular directive restriction

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a way to write a directive that just applies to a specific element + attribute + attribute value?

My very first intention would be to have separate directives, for modularity and maintenance purposes, but I'm afraid that's not possible as I get an error from Angular telling me there are multiple directives matching the element.

So my scenario is as follows: I want to write my own input elements, e.g.

`<input type="time-picker">`
`<input type="date-picker">`

so I did

```
app.directive('input', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: function ($element, $attrs) {
      if ($attrs.type === 'date-picker' || $attrs.type === 'time-picker') {
        return $attrs.type + '.html';
      }
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      if ($attrs.type === 'date-picker') {
        console.log('date-picker');
      }
      else if($attrs.type === 'time-picker') {
        console.log('time-picker');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This works well as long as there are no other input elements in the page.

If I put

```
<input type="time-picker">
<input type="date-picker">
```

it works fine. Now if I add

```
<input type="text">
```

the whole page hangs.

See my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pWc3K/8/

Answer (score 1):

If you change your html to this:

```
<input type="text" time-picker> <input type="text" date-picker>
```

Then you could wire up your directives based on those attributes like so:

```
app.directive('timePicker', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        ...
    }
});
app.directive('datePicker', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        ...
    }
});
```

Putting time-picker/date-picker in an input type for an element isn't really valid. If you read up on the angular docs for [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#directivedefinitionobject) you'll find a whole list of the different things you can associate on. The four ones are:

```
E - Element name: <my-directive></my-directive>
A - Attribute: <div my-directive="exp"> </div>
C - Class: <div class="my-directive: exp;"></div>
M - Comment: <!-- directive: my-directive exp -->
```

Comment: Hi Mathew, what do you think of this implementation? https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/L8DZ8WWsXCo

Answer (score 0):

Try and understand In AngularJs custom directives created can have following restrictions:

The restrict option is typically set to:

'A' - only matches attribute name

'E' - only matches element name

'C' - only matches class name

‘M’ – only comments

These restrictions can all be combined as needed:
for eg:
'AEC' - matches either attribute or element or class name